# 1080p videos encoded in H264 are not playing in Safari

Tags: quicktime, h.264, 1080p

I'm doing *HTTP live streaming* of `1080p` video encoded in `H264` with `Main` profile level `4.1`.

However `Safari` is unable to play the video. I can only hear the audio.

The streaming is working fine with `Chrome` and `Firefox`.

When I try to download the video segment in `.ts` format, `QuickTime player` is unable to play while `VLC player` is playing.

I'm assuming that something is wrong with the video encoding. The same video is doing fine with `Baseline @3.0` in `720p` resolution. What could be the issue?

Comment: Show [mediainfo](http://www.mediaarea.net) readout of file. Use View -> Text mode.

Comment: Link to mediainfo readout file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx7SpoNBrww7YlB5ZTVqRTNIUEU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Why does your "standard" say PAL when your video is supposed to be progressive?

Comment: Fixed the issue. Transcoding the video to progressive worked.